# Android: Increase height of linear layout while adding ImageViews to it

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to add ImageViews by drag and drop to a LinearLayout. After adding 5 ImageViews, the LinearLayout size should increase and the ImageViews should add in the Next line of the LinerLayout. Basically I am trying to add 5 sets of ImageViews in the LinearLayout. First 5 in first line, Next 5 in 2nd line etc...

Any idea how to achieve this. I tried it in the following manner but the imageviews are not added after increasing the height of the LinerLayout.

```
case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:

            if(v == findViewById(R.id.dragDropHereLinear)) {
                View view = (View) event.getLocalState();
                ViewGroup viewgroup = (ViewGroup) view.getParent();
                //viewgroup.removeView(view);                   

                ImageView iv = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());


                LinearLayout containView = (LinearLayout) v;

                TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvDragDropHere);

                if(count > 4 ) {
                    count = 0;
                    containView.getLayoutParams().height = containView.getLayoutParams().height + 200;
                    containView.requestLayout();
                    //invalidate();
                }                   

                iv.setPadding(5, 0, 5, 0);
                containView.addView(iv);
                iv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                count++;

            } else {
                View view = (View) event.getLocalState();
                view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                Context context = getApplicationContext();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "problem in dropping the image", 
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            break;
```

Answer (score 0):

You just set in your layout height ="match_parent" in your xml file or you can set dynamically like this.....

```
 LayoutParams layoutParams = (LayoutParams) layoutname.getLayoutParams();
 layoutParams.width = FrameLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT;
 layoutParams.width = FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
```

Answer (score 0):

For your requirement, I suggest you using **FlowLayout**.

**FlowLayout** is Extended linear layout that wrap its content when there is no place in the current line.
you can find that out [here](https://github.com/ApmeM/android-flowlayout)

Comment: Hi, I want to add views dynamically. But the FlowLayout is different then my requirement. Could you please guide anything else. Thanks for your help.